# Dropping Webpacker from Rails 6. Now asset compilation doesn't work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, webpacker

`ruby '3.0.1'` `'rails', '~> 6.1.2'`

I am dropping Webpacker from a rails project. I assume it was originally created using `rails new` with the webpacker flag to generate it but I do not know for sure. All I've done so far was remove yarn, browersify, babel, and etc source files and then moved all of my javascripts and stylesheets to `app/assets` and `app/vendor`.

I also added this to `application.html.erb`:

```
    <%= stylesheet_link_tag "application", media: "all", "data-turbolinks-track" => "reload" %>
    <%= javascript_include_tag "application", "data-turbolinks-track" => "reload" %>
```

For a while, things were working. I was correcting paths, fixing small errors, and etc. Then after I restarted the server once, I was given a new error and now I'm stuck.

```
Sprockets::Rails::Helper::AssetNotPrecompiled in Universes#index

Showing /var/app/app/views/layouts/application.html.erb where line #8 raised:

application.css
```

Here's what I know so far:

- I don't use an application.css. I have a `app/assets/stylesheets/application.scss` instead.
- If I remove the stylesheet `stylesheet_link_tag` call, I get a similar one for `application.js`.
- I'm sure I have the sass-rails gem installed so it should be using application.scss instead.
- I've never used the base rails asset pipeline before. Only the webpacker-way of doing things. So I can assume very basic things are missing.

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: make sure `//= link_directory ../stylesheets .css` in your `app/assets/config/manifest.js`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Lam Phan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12219679/lam-phan) had what I needed. My `assets/config/manifest.js` was not configured correctly. I restored it to:

```
//= link_tree ../images
//= link_directory ../javascripts .js
//= link_directory ../stylesheets .css
```

and then made sure `application.scss` and `application.js` were at those paths. It was all easy after that. Thank you very much for your time.

Answer (score 0):

For application.scss you should make sure you have the `sass-rails` gem in your gemfile.

Other than that maybe some help would come from: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#in-development

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I've double checked that I have the sass-rails gem. Updating my post.